# Simple MS SQL Bug

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

I am very new to MS SQL and am trying to get all duplicate emails in a table.  I found a similar query that works for MySQL but when run it in MS SQL I get the error Invalid column name 'ct'.

The query I run is:

```
SELECT   
  [ShipEmail], 
  COUNT(*) as ct

FROM [ShipWorksDefault].[dbo].[Customers] GROUP BY [ShipEmail] HAVING [ct] > 1
```

I am guessing there is something very simple I am over looking.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Just change the HAVING clause to not use the column alias:

HAVING count(*) > 1

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the alias in the having clause. Try:

```
SELECT   
  [ShipEmail], 
  COUNT(*) as ct

FROM [ShipWorksDefault].[dbo].[Customers] GROUP BY [ShipEmail] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   
  [ShipEmail], 
  COUNT(*) as ct
FROM [ShipWorksDefault].[dbo].[Customers] 
GROUP BY [ShipEmail] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

or

```
SELECT   
  [ShipEmail], 
  COUNT(*) as ct
FROM [ShipWorksDefault].[dbo].[Customers] 
GROUP BY [ShipEmail] HAVING COUNT([ShipEmail]) > 1
```

Comment: Did you mean having count(*) >1? Also I tried the second version and got a differnt number of records returned than the having count(*)>1 version